# Can I delete a row of a table by a trigger which is included in the table it self?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to delete a row of a table through a trigger. And the trigger is written in the same table.Currently I get an error #1442 - Can't update table 'Traffic' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Comment: Means on delete of row `A` you want to delete row `B` ?

Comment: after insert row A I want to delete row B

Comment: so what you can do write a trigger on insert of table. inside the trigger you can delete the row.

Comment: I did it then it gives me this error - #1442 - Can't update table 'Traffic' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Comment: You can't do that because it's an infinite loop. Delete rows using regular queries, don't do stupid stuff using triggers just because the sake of "coolness".